# Login-bar with Spring Secuirty

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I'm developing a Spring-based web application by using Spring Boot and Spring Security.

I've a specific and detailed login page `{mywebapp}/login`, but I'd like to have also a login-bar in every page with the aim to offer a *fast login* facility.
How can I setup my project to achieve this goal (by using Java Config, hence annotations and methods, avoiding xml files)?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question well, you have to use whatever templating system you are using to generate the html pages and add a section to your layout that is shared across all pages consisting of a form like this (I'm assuming you are using spring-security defaults):

```
<form action="${request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I'm also assuming you have your login detailed page fully working using spring-security with user/password default login support.

Hope it helps.

Comment: N.B. those are not the default settings for a modern Javaconfig app (e.g. I believe /login is correct, as per the original post).

Comment: I believe that is the path for displaying the login page, not to perform authentication

Comment: I don't think so. See [here in the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java#L342). The login page is a GET, the processing URL only works with POST, but they are the same by default.

Comment: I used the default values from spring-security core implementation. Effectively, when using java config the configurer (v3.2) overrides the spring-security defaults for the processing url (as you well noted), and also the input field names. Updated the form above accordingly. Thanks for the tip.